# How to make inner loop in jQuery using $.each

Tags: jquery, dynamic, html-table

I have developed generated dynamic tables and rows in jQuery based on input value. I am facing problem when I am trying to make inner loop using `$.each`. But it is not giving proper output.

```
$('#box').click(function () {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@routes.Application.getB()',
        data: {
            truckid: 'ean123'
        },
        beforeSend: function () {

        },
        success: function (data) {

            $("#ajaxload").hide();
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                $("#box_content").append('<table  class="boxtablestructure">');
                $("#box_content").append('<th >No : ' + data[i] + '</th>');
                $("#box_content").append('<tr>');
                $("#box_content").append('<th style=""> Rollno</th>');
                $("#box_content").append('<tbody>');
                $("#box_content").append('</tbody>');
                $("#box_content").append('</table></br>');

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '@routes.Application.getU()',
                    data: {
                        docid: data[i]
                    },
                    beforeSend: function () {

                    },
                    success: function (items) {

                        $.each(items, function (j, item) {

                            $("#box_content").find("tbody").append('<tr>');
                            $("#box_content").find("tbody").append('<td>' + item + '</td>');
                            $("#box_content").find("tbody").append('</tr>');

                        });
                    }
                });

            });
```

In the above code `getB()` function return some values, with that value tables will be generated. If `getB()` returns length 2 then two tables will be generated. It was generated successfully. then Each table should generated row and columns based on `getB()` value. Here is the problem, all the values are assigned to each table. For example `getB()` return 1010,1011. My need is will pass 1010 ajax parameter in inner `$.each` and it is returning some values corresponding to 1010. I need to assign this as same table rows.

```
No: 1010
-----------------------------
Rollno
-----------------------------
1234
1235


No 1011
--------------------------------
Rollno
---------------------------------
1236
1237
```

the above is my expected output, but I am getting:

```
No 1010
---------------------------------
Rollno
---------------------------------
1234
1235
1236
1237

No 1011
----------------------------------
Rollno 
----------------------------------
1234
1235
1236
1237
```

Please anyone help me

Comment: there are multiple problems.. you are using `.append()` like a string concatenation operator, which is wrong

Comment: How can i resolve this dude.I want above output. for that what i have to do. Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try your `success callback` like,

```
success: function (data) {
        $("#ajaxload").hide();
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            // creates table and its header
            var table='<table  class="boxtablestructure">';
            table += '<tr><th>No : '+data[i]+'</th></tr>';
            table += '<tr><th style=""> Rollno</th></tr>';
            table += '</table></br>';
            // append table in box_content
            $("#box_content").append(table);

            // creates tbody and append to last inserted table
            var $tbody = $('<tbody>').appendTo('#box_content table:last');

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@routes.Application.getU()',
                data: {
                    docid: data[i]
                },
                beforeSend: function () {
                },
                success: function (items) {
                    // append the rows in last created table body
                    $.each(items, function (j, item) {
                        $tbody.append('<tr><td>' + item + '</td></tr>');
                    });
                }
            });

        });
  } // end success callback
```

Comment: the second ajax request is a async request then what happenss

Comment: got answer. with above code. thanks Rohan and Arun.. Superv.. thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You can't use .append() like a string concatenation operator, try

```
$('#box').click(function () {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@routes.Application.getB()',
        data: {
            truckid: 'ean123'
        },
        beforeSend: function () {

        },
        success: function (data) {

            $("#ajaxload").hide();
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                var $table = $('<table  class="boxtablestructure">' +
                    '<th >No : ' + data[i] + '</th>' +
                    '<tr>' +
                    '<th style=""> Rollno</th>' +
                    '<tbody>' +
                    '</tbody>' +
                    '</table><br />').appendTo('#box_content'),
                    $tbody = $table.find('tbody');

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '@routes.Application.getU()',
                    data: {
                        docid: data[i]
                    },
                    beforeSend: function () {

                    },
                    success: function (items) {

                        $.each(items, function (j, item) {
                            var $tr = $('<tr />');

                            $tr.append('<td>' + item + '</td>');

                            $tr.appendTo($tbody)
                        });
                    }
                });

            });
```

Comment: super bro. but one problem . the result printed twice . but the result is correct. i am to limit to one time. now i am getting is No: 1010
1010
Rollno

1234
1235
1234
1235                                                                             
     1011
1236
1236

Comment: @user3454863 that could be the problem of your ajax response.. can you check whether the ajax response is returning the values multiple times